# Получение компонента находящегося в определённых координатах узла

Tags: java, javafx

У меня есть HBox в котором я прокручиваю анимацию из множества ImageView на подобие рулетки. И после окончания анимации нужно получить информацию какая картинка оказалась в центре HBox

Каким способом получить эти данные?

Answer (score 0):

Хранение элементов в HBox реализовано при помощи `ObservableList<Node>`.
С помощью метода `public ObservableList<Node> getChildren()` вы сможете получить Лист всех элементов в HBox'е.
Чтобы получить средний элемент из `ObservableList` просто поделите его размер на два - `list.get(list.size()/2)`

Comment: Не уверен что это подойдет из за того что к концу анимации на экране изображения могут быть в не очевидном положении, но идея хорошая. Попытаюсь решить проблему с её помощью